# How to set default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, current-time

I have created an entity and I want to give `createdDate` variable, the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default value, how can I do that?

```
@Column(name = "created_date")
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

Comment: you can use @CreationTimestamp.. similar answer you can refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811845/setting-a-jpa-timestamp-column-to-be-generated-by-the-database

Comment: You want to create database column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  or want to store current timestamp in column from jpa ?

Comment: I want to store current timestampt default valie in jpa

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@CreatedDate` with Spring Data JPA provided `AuditingEntityListener`

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
class Entity {
   ...
   @CreatedDate
   @Column(name = "created_date")
   private LocalDateTime createdDate;
   ...
}
```

Then use `@EnableJpaAuditing` on your application main class to enable the Spring Data JPA Auditing features for the application.

A good tutorial about [Spring Data JPA : Auditing](https://springbootdev.com/2018/03/13/spring-data-jpa-auditing-with-createdby-createddate-lastmodifiedby-and-lastmodifieddate/)