# On Update: Auto Update Date/Time Field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an equivalent of MySQLs on update field for SQL server?

> With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   clauses, the column has the current
>   timestamp for its default value, and
>   is automatically updated.

What I am looking for is to have a date/time field and every time I update a record it updates the field with the date/time it was updated automatically?

If it doesn't exist, I guess I'll have to go manual.

Thanks all

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 Auto Updated DateTime Column - LastUpdated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001/sql-server-2005-auto-updated-datetime-column-lastupdated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a trigger. I'm not sure if this is what you mean by "manual"

Comment: JUst make sure you write the trigger so that it can handle multiple reocrd updates.