# Auto update time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework, auto-update

I would like to have two columns in my table to store the add-time and update-time. As the name suggests, the add-time is the time when a row was first added; the update-time is the last time a row was updated. I can implement first by defaulting value to `GETDATE()`. As for the second, @Jeremy suggested using triggers here:

[On Update: Auto Update Date/Time Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713339/on-update-auto-update-date-time-field)

1. Is there any easier way?
2. If I implement a trigger, does that mean two `UPDATE` statements (or one `INSERT` and one `UPDATE` in case the row is just created) have to be executed?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** For the second part of the question, this is the trigger I have in my database:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_AddUpdateTime]
   ON [dbo].[AddUpdateTime]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    UPDATE r
       SET UpdateTime = GETDATE()
      FROM AddUpdateTime r
      JOIN inserted i
        ON i.Id = r.Id
END
```

Does this mean that an additional update statement will be executed whenever I make an update to AddUpdateTime table, or MSSQL is smart enough to recognise that I am updating the same record and save both changes at the same time?

Comment: Are you always updating/inserting through a stored proc? You could just get that to insert the time.

Comment: No, I am using Entity Framework actually.

Comment: I edited my answer to have an option for entity framework.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could make sure all inserts and updates go through a stored procedure that inserts the time.
2. No, the insert trigger will modify the values so that it's only one statement.

**Edit:** For entity framework could you implement the OnSavingChanges event to insert the update-time field ([see here](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/11/dynamicdata-automatic-column-update-for.html))? This is moving the responsibility from the DB to the Code which you may or may not be comfortable with.

Comment: So there seems to be some confusion. You said that the trigger will not cause an extra UPDATE statement to be executed, but that is the opposite of what @gbn said above!

Comment: I edited my question for you to see the trigger I added to the database.

Answer (score 2):

1. Other ways:

   - Use a stored procedure to wrap the updates
   - You can do `UPDATE MyTable SET ..., UpdatedWhen = DEFAULT...`
2. You need an UPDATE trigger that itself has one more UPDATE. Using a default on the table means you don't need a trigger for INSERT

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on @paulsm4's answer, I don't want to use a stored procedure. I also don't want to manually set the UpdateTime whenever I want to update a record, as I want the solution to be generic to use it in many tables.

Comment: As for your second comment, I am only using the default value for the add-time, because it is only set the first time a record is created. But the update-time needs to be updated whenever I make any change to a record.

Comment: @Promather: you can use the DEFAULT keyword in a update to set it. SO if the default is GETDATE(), then UpdatedWhen will be *updated* with the latest date. Even if you use a trigger, this means that the GETDATE is only mentioned in the constraint: not in code.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. But still I need to always add UpdatedWhen = DEFAULT to each UPDATE statement, which is not a good practice.

Comment: @Promather: It sounds like your default value on the 'add-time' will take care of that field on INSERT.  An UPDATE trigger, as gbn suggests, will fire whenever a row is updated.  The trigger, in turn, needs to do an UPDATE to set the 'update-time'.  Makes sense?

Comment: OK, it makes now. But the problem is that the answer to the second question seems to contradict that of Ray's below, so not sure which one is correct! I edited my question to include the trigger I created in my database.

Comment: @Promather: your trigger looks correct and is all you need. An insert trigger is not needed. Note: if you use the DB server for the GETDATE() then the same server generates it. You could get discrepancies if the server running EF generates the values between multiple client servers or between DB and client server.

Answer (score 1):

In entity framework, you can use the partial class to extend the business logic. In this case, you can use **OnPropertyChanged** to set the update-time to DateTime.Now. You can use this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716747.aspx) as a guidance.

Answer (score 0):

1) "Auto update" and "triggers" doesn't really sound like the way to go.

2) SQL Server has a (relatively new) "merge" statement.  But that doesn't really sound like what you're looking for, either.

3) Instead:

a) If primary key doesn't exist (if "new"), then INSERT.  In this case, first time = last time = GETDATE().

b) Otherwise, if the primary key already exists, then UPDATE.  Your update will update only the "last time" column (along with the rest of the fields you need to update for this record.

4) Perhaps you can wrap this logic in a stored procedure?

5) Again - the key is to update *BOTH* "first time" and "last time*, the *FIRST TIME*, and then update *ONLY* "last time" all SUBSEQUENT times.

Comment: Well, I want my record to get automatically updated, without having to write a stored procedure as I am using Entity Framework and I am not sure how to make Entity Framework use my stored procedure for inserting/updating records.

Answer (score 0):

1. They might be an easier way but using triggers will be more effective and will guarantee no mater how records inseted or updated (from .net code or direct table inserts/updates), those two fields are populated
2. To Gurantee that only one trigger get fired each time, combine insert and update trigger

   ```
    CREATE TRIGGER <trigger name> ON TableA for INSERT,UPDATE
   ```

   And do conditional checking to distinguish between two actions

   ```
    IF UPDATE
   ```