# SQL Server automatic update datetimestamp field

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 R2" I am trying to insert a formula in SQL Server that will update the current value in the `LastUpdatedTimestamp` field to now i.e. `getdate()` every time the record is updated.

Comment: There really is no question here.

Comment: I just found I must use a trigger I was hoping that I could have used a built in function. Thanks guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 Auto Updated DateTime Column - LastUpdated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001/sql-server-2005-auto-updated-datetime-column-lastupdated)

Answer (score 8):

You can have a default constraint on your `DateTime` field that will cause the current date/time to be inserted when you insert a new row.

From there on, you need to work with a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger that will update your date/time column each time the row is updated.

You cannot do this second task (updating a date/time stamp when updating the row) using a "formula" as you said - it just doesn't work that way in SQL Server.

You need to provide a trigger something along those lines:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgYourTableUpdateTimestamp
  ON dbo.YourTable FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
   UPDATE 
      dbo.YourTable 
   SET 
      YourTimeStampColumn = GETDATE()
   FROM 
      Inserted Ins
   WHERE
      dbo.YourTable.SomeUniqueId = Ins.SomeUniqueId
END
```