# How do I create and set fields for insert_date and last_modified_date in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'd like to record the insert date and an update date on a table.
What is the best way to do this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What tables or data are you storing?  SQL generally has a getdate() that retrieves the date and time.

Comment: best way is to push it from you data-access code (like SubSonic do) or write triggers for update and insert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744067/sql-server-automatic-update-datetimestamp-field/5746102#5746102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Insert Date you can use the following trigger:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_DATE ON TABLE1  
   FOR INSERT
    AS

    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON

        UPDATE TABLE1
        SET  CreatedOn = GETDATE()
                FROM TABLE1 A
        INNER JOIN Inserted INS ON (INS.Id = A.Id)

        SET NOCOUNT OFF

    END
```

and for Update you can use the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update ON TABLE1
FOR UPDATE
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE  TABLE1
    SET   UpdatedOn = GETDATE()
        FROM    TABLE1 A
            INNER JOIN Inserted INS ON (A.Id = INS.Id)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
```

Answer (score 3):

For the insert date column, you can set the column default to `GETDATE()` (or `GETUTCDATE()`).

For the update date, you would need to use a trigger to set the column to the current date whenever there's an update.

Comment: Does anyone have an example of a trigger like that?