# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP defaults to "null" value, possible reasons?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

So if I run a virtual instance of IIS on localhost to test some site, I have a datebase field with a default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` that upon insertion always defaults to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`, which is, as I understand, the null-like value for DateTime in these scenarios.

Why is this happening? Can't I get the actual time and date to go in this field?

I've tried using `getdate(), sysdatetime()` and whichever else alternatives and it's the same thing.

The field in the C# code is:

```
public DateTime LastModification { get; set; }
```

Any workaround around this?

I'm using the correct mappings as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you using ORM? Which one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server automatic update datetimestamp field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744067/sql-server-automatic-update-datetimestamp-field)

Comment: I don't need a trigger for multiple operations. Just INSERT, so only one default possible.

Comment: @user3046061, can you post the mapping class which contains the field in question?

Comment: @user3046061, seems [this](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/471061) is what you are facing

Comment: That explains it. Post an answer with this so I can accept it.