# NHibernate - Version as DateTime, generated in DB

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to assign a version column to my table and I want the version to be generated from the DB (getDate()). My mapping looks like that:

```
Version(x => x.Version).Index("idx_Version").Generated.Always();
```

but when I'm trying to insert a row, I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Version'... column does not allow nulls.
```

I've also tried a different approach and mapped the column as an regular column like this:

```
Map(x => x.Version).Index("idx_Version").Generated.Always();
```

but it's generated nulls on that column...

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe this tells NHibernate that the DB will be responsible for filling this column. How is the DB handling it? Did you set a default on the column in the DB?

Comment: I set a default value of getDate() but it generates it only on insert, not on update. How can I set the value for generated field?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are using MS SQL DB. There are some similar answers:

- [Auto Updated DateTime Column - LastUpdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36011/1679310)
- [automatic update datetimestamp field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5746102/1679310)

Summary: implement the trigger on UPDATE to have your column changed even during the UPDATE (not only INSERT with GetDate())

Or (I would suggest this appraoch) use a [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) which will do for you exactly what you want.